# Looking for how to put user input into my code with a loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Delete0()
Dim myRow As Variant
myRow = InputBox("What row does the data start in?")

Dim myColumn As Variant
myColumn = InputBox("What Column does the data start in? (number format, i.e A=1, B=2)")

Dim LR As Long
Dim FR As Long

LR = 1 'where to have myRow be entered
FR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until LR > FR
    If Cells(LR, 17).Value > 0 Then 'Where to have myColumn be entered
        LR = LR + 1
    Else
        Cells(LR, 17).EntireRow.Delete
        FR = FR - 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

This is my current code but I want to add user input on the data may change from week to week starting at a different row and the values being deleted in a different column. How would I enter this into my current code?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below should be the simplest way to do it given your provided code. I've changed the data types of myRow and myColumn to Long to throw an error right on input.

```
Sub Delete0()
Dim myRow As Long
myRow = InputBox("What row does the data start in?")

Dim myColumn As Long
myColumn = InputBox("What Column does the data start in? (number format, i.e A=1, B=2)")

Dim LR As Long
Dim FR As Long

LR = myRow 'where to have myRow be entered
FR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do Until LR > FR
    If Cells(LR, myColumn).Value > 0 Then 'Where to have myColumn be entered
        LR = LR + 1
    Else
        Cells(LR, myColumn).EntireRow.Delete
        FR = FR - 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```